# MongoDB: Convert Array to CSV for Complex Data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We have MongoDB documents called Notes that consist of a `Layout` section and a `Data` section. The `Data` section uses the `Layout` section to describe and label the fields. For example, here is a simplified sample of a Note document:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5aafefbecbf20b364c14d037"),
  "Title" : "Some Note Name",
    "CreatedDate" : ISODate("2018-10-22T13:12:20.343-04:00"),
  "Layout" : {
    "Name" : "Some Layout Name",
    "ComponentId" : "531a5112-2467-410c-a477-936c6527256b",
    "Tabs" : [
      {
        "Name" : "Some Tab Name",
        "Icon" : "tab",
        "Sections" : [
          {
            "Name" : "Some Section Name",
            "MappingId" : "SomeSectionId",
            "Sets" : [
              {
                "SetId" : NumberLong("1"),
                "Questions" : [
                  {
                    "MappingId" : "SomeShortAnswerId",
                    "Label" : "Some Short Answer Label",
                    "Set" : NumberLong("1"),
                    "QuestionType" : "ShortAnswer"
                  },
                  {
                    "MappingId" : "SomeMultipleChoiceId",
                    "Label" : "Some Multiple Choice Label",
                    "Set" : NumberLong("1"),
                    "QuestionType" : "MultipleChoice"
                  },
                  {
                    "MappingId" : "SomeYesNoId",
                    "Label" : "Some Yes No Label",
                    "Set" : NumberLong("1"),
                    "QuestionType" : "YesNo"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "Data" : {
    "SomeSectionId" : [
      {
        "SomeShortAnswerId" : "blah blah blah",
        "SomeMultipleChoiceId" : [
          "Answer 1",
          "Answer 2",
          "Answer 3"
        ],
        "SomeYesNoId" : true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can see that the `Data` section field names correspond to the `Layout.Tabs.Sections` `MappingId` and `Questions.MappingId`. My current query works for returning just the data portion:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate( 
  [
    { $project: { CreatedDate: 1, Data: 1 } },
    { $unwind: "$Data.SomeSectionId" },
    {
        $addFields: {
            "Data.SomeSectionId.CreatedDate": "$CreatedDate",
            "Data.SomeSectionId._id": "$_id"
        }
    },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$Data.SomeSectionId" } }
  ]
)
```

and the data returned:

```
{
  "SomeShortAnswerId" : "blah blah blah",
  "SomeMultipleChoiceId" : [
    "Answer 1, Answer 2, Answer 3"
  ]
  "SomeYesNoId" : true
}
```

Unfortunately, this data is passed on to a reporting application that has limitations and cannot handle the sub-array values for the multiple choice question answers.

I need to format the data like this instead:

```
{
  "SomeShortAnswerId" : "blah blah blah",
  "SomeMultipleChoiceId" : "Answer 1, Answer 2, Answer 3",
  "SomeYesNoId" : true
}
```

What makes this whole process so complicated is that besides the `Data` field name, all other field names are found in the `Layout` section (`MappingId`s).

Can anyone suggest a way to convert the answer arrays to a single text comma separated value given the self-describing nature of our `Note` documents? This is killing me...

**Update**

I may not have made it clear that the Note contents above does not have fixed fields. I cannot count on `SomeShortAnswerId`, `SomeMultipleChoiceId`, or `SomeYesNoId` being there. Those fields might be or there might be additional multiple choice fields to convert to CSV format. It's all based on the contents of the `Layout` section.

Is it possible to iterate through all the fields in a section (`Data`) without having to specify the actual field name? If that was possible, I could apply a $reduce to every field.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/

Comment: @AlexBlex I had already used the $reduce function in a hard-coded query (not shown). See the additional Update section for more information related to this question.

Comment: "convert the answer arrays to a single text comma separated value" is one problem and "Is it possible to iterate through all the fields" is a completely different one. Please try to limit scope of your question to a single problem in the future. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/ is for iteration over properties. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/ to apply reduce to array values only.

Comment: thanks @AlexBlex. i usually try to limit my posts to focused questions, but invariably someone always asks "why are you doing this" and that was the follow edit i added. i'll review those links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestions from Alex Blex, I was able to craft a solution using the aggregation functions, `$objectToArray`, `$reduce`, `$group`, and `$arrayToObject` with liberal use of `$project`, `$replaceRoot`, `$group`, `$addToSet`, and a few other common ones. The key was really the use of `$objectToArray` and `$arrayToObject`, as it didn't require any knowledge of the property names.

Here's my slightly modified query here:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "_id": { $eq: ObjectId("5aafefbecbf20b364c14d037") }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            CreatedDate: 1,
            data: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT.Data" }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            "data.v.CreatedDate": "$CreatedDate",
            "data.v._id": "$_id"
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$data" },
    { $unwind: "$data.v" },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data.v" } },
    { $project: { data: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } } },
    { $unwind: "$data" },
    {
        $project: {
            "Question": "$data.k",
            "Answer": {
                $switch: {
                    branches: [
                        {
                            case: { $eq: [{ $type: "$data.v" }, "array"] },
                            then: {
                                $reduce: {
                                    input: "$data.v",
                                    initialValue: "",
                                    in: {
                                        $concat: [
                                            "$$value",
                                            { $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$$value", ""] }, then: "", else: ", " } },
                                            { $concat: ["'", "$$this", "'"] }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    default: "$data.v"
                }
            },
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            section: { $addToSet: { "k": "$Question", "v": "$Answer" } }
        }
    },
    { $project: { section: { $arrayToObject: "$section" } } },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$section" } }
])
```